# Cómo ocultar descripción de un Web Service SOAP ASMX

Tags: webservice

Tengo un servicio Web `ASMX`, funcionalmente esta correcto, pero los de seguridad me piden que cuando hago clic sobre un método, NO me muestras la descripción y nombres de variables y demás datos "sensibles" del Web Service, no sé si eso se pueda ya que un `SOAP` siempre expone toda la descripción de la información, pero bueno espero que por este medio me orienten un poco más al respecto.

Les pongo un ejemplo en una imagen en recuadro Rojo (lo que no quisiera que se muestre):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué parte se muestra la descipción? ¿Podrías compartir un ejemplo para saber en qué parte se muestra esa información que dices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se porque razón te dicen que no DEBE verse esos datos, cuando lo normal es que si lo vean ya que la gente que los ocupe sabe de igual forma que tu que parámetro enviar, que tipo de dato enviar y que va a recibir. Por otro lado, una persona X, puede ver, quizás entender un poco de programación y saber que hay datos, que tiene nombres y tipo de dato, pero en que afectaría que el supiera eso? Si tu servicio web es el que se encarga de tomar esos valores, verificar si corresponden o no...

Pero de todas formas, con esto puedes ocultar toda la parte de `Description`

```
<system.web.services>
    <protocols>
        <remove name="Documentation"/>
    </protocols>
</system.web.services>
```

Comment: La verdad yo opino lo mismo que tu, pero en el ámbito laboral hay cada persona con la que uo se choca, que muchas veces ni conocimiento ni fundamentos tienen y nomas perjudican dando instrucciones de hacer lo planteado en el post. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @RSillerico te entiendo, podrias plantear que lo que ellos quieren lograr no beneficia mucho en tu proyecto, sin embargo como te comento en mi respuesta dejar eso te va ayudar a esconder la descripción. Me comentas cualquier cosa saludos!